# What is the best way to avoid GUI getting stuck when I'm sample my class

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dumpFile = e.UserState as DumpFile;
        lblNumberOfPacketsTabSniffer2.Text = dumpFile._packetsCount.ToString("#,##0");
        lblTrafficRateTabSniffer2.Text = (dumpFile._bitsPerSecond * 
    }
```

in this function i'am sample my class but because of the high speed my GUI get stuck, if i want to sample my class every 500 milliseconds for example that is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Does calling Application.DoEvents(); at the end of your ProgressChanged method help?

Comment: Application.DoEvents() causes all of the UI events to get handled.  Or according to Microsoft "Processes all Windows messages currently in the message queue.". More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Comment: Please don't call `DoEvents()`. Those habits learnt in 20th century VB were bad back then. They still suck today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at

[BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient
>   solution.